# Ricatti Differential equation and initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to find a polynomial that solves the following Riccati-equation.

$y'=\frac {-2}{x}-2xy+\frac {2y^2}{x}$

How to solve it?

Furthermore I need to solve the initial value problem for arbitrary $(x_{0}, y_{0})$ out of $\mathbb {R}\setminus{0}$

Thanks for your help

Comment: Ok I've tried it: I took $v=y/x$ and substituted. What I get is : $v'= \frac{-2}{x^3}-2vx+\frac{2v^2}{x}-\frac{v}{x}$   Have I done anything wrong? Doesn't seem too helpful to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the form of the ODE we observe that the solutions $y(x)$ are even functions. So, the change of variable $X=x^2$ allows a first simplifixation. Then, the usual change of function for Riccati's ODE leads to a linear second order ODE.

[image]